# TFPTimer not 'Ticking'

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I'm writing a game which I've attempted to separate between the interface, and the simulator (both of which run with separate timing circuits - with the theory being animations will sync, and simulation can run only 10 times a second... or something)

I'm having issues with my TFPTimer. Its initialised with the Games constructor like so:

```
//Create the game timer
InternalTimer := TFPTimer.Create(nil);
//Set the OnTick callback
InternalTimer.OnTimer := @OnTick;
//Set the timer interval
InternalTimer.Interval := DEFAULT_INTERNAL_TIMER; // =10
//Start the timer
InternalTimer.StartTimer;
```

The problem is OnTick never seems to be called. I've got a seperate loop running under the client with an SDL_Delay in it. Do I need to eventise TFPTimer somehow? Should I give it its own thread (or does it already have one?) Any ideas on making my timer work?

Thanks

Lachlan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events come from the main event loop. If your program is not eventdriven in the Delphi/Lazarus sense it will probably not work.

Try an application.processmessages inbetween sleeps

Comment: Ahhhh... well in my completely non Delphi/Lazarus program with no TApplication, I suspect it may be worth simply rewriting it to work in a separate thread with a fresh timer class to avoid that hussle. Thank you. (I listed Lazarus as a category because I was using the Lazarus Component Library for the timer)

Comment: The main eventloop principles are in sysutils, not lazarus. It is possible to use such event driven stuff in console apps, services/daemons etc, like in Delphi. See e.g. custapp. I don't have much experience with that though, ask on the maillist/forum